# Passing a property setter as a function parameter

Tags: swift

I'd like to understand if it is possible to pass a property setter as a parameter.

Say I have this simple class

```
class MyValue {
    private var privateValue: Int = 0

    var value: Int {
        get {
            return privateValue
        }
        set {
            privateValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

And a function that takes a callback:

```
func giveValue(callback: Int -> Void) {
    callback(1337)
}
```

Now if I want to set my value to the callback value, I would do:

```
let myValue = MyValue()

giveValue { i in
    myValue.value = i
}

print(myValue.value) // 1337
```

I know that I can do

```
giveValue { myValue.value = $0 }
```

But **is there a way in Swift 2 to directly give a setter as a parameter?** Something like:

```
giveValue(myValue.value.setter)
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this was this case in Swift 2, but in Swift 3, [inout parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID173) may get you close to this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that.

In swift, [computed properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) have get and set which are being called *automatically* whenever you set the value of ask for it.

Answer (score -1):

Now with Swift (5.9.2 at least) you can pass in a value with setters.

> set(yourValue){
>
> }

Comment: This would be much better if you showed a complete example. Right now your answer makes little sense.